# Automatically refreshes background of app with a new color in andorid

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the background of my android app automatically after few milliseconds. So first I created a drawable resource file "colorchange.xml" with the content

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="false" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/color1" android:duration="1" />
<item android:drawable="@color/color2" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@color/color3" android:duration="3" />
<item android:drawable="@color/color4" android:duration="4" />
<item android:drawable="@color/color5" android:duration="5" />
```

And I used this as background in my main xml file
Now only color1 is set as background. Animation of colors is not showing as background.

What is the problem in this and how can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: In which part of code your are starting animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check when are you starting the animation. According [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start()) you should not use animation on *onCreate()* method.

> Note: Do not call this in the onCreate(Bundle) method of your
>   activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to
>   the window. If you want to play the animation immediately without
>   requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the
>   onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) method in your activity, which will get
>   called when Android brings your window into focus.

**EDIT** - An example of how to use *Animation*:

```
// Load the View that will host the animation and
// set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.example_view);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorchange);

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) linearLayout.getBackground();

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: I didn't added it in any of the java files.
I just created a xml resource file(colorchange.xml) and in main xml file I set this colorchange.xml as background

Comment: You should start animation. Look at my example in response.

Comment: i have some buttons in my main xml so if I added an image then it will overlap the buttons. In that case image will not act as background

Comment: "ImageView" is only an example, use your "Layout" instead. Check EDITED answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can define your colors in `colors.xml` like this:

```
<color name="yourcolor">#0FFF</color>
```

then you can use it like this:

```
<item android:drawable=@colors/yourcolor android:duration="5" />
```

Comment: Ok i did the same and it run. But it is not changing color automatically that means colorchange.xml is not working
How can I overcome it ?

Comment: The answer I provided was designed to solve your first problem. But for changing background periodically I suggest you take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8146089/2101822 hope it helps ;)

Comment: I don't want to use image as background but colors

Answer (score 0):

You shold define your colors in value/colors.xml file and use it like android:drawable="@color/MyGreen"